# Efficient way to get timestamp of scheduled stream from multiple Youtube channels via youtube api?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm making a list that organizes the start time of scheduled streams on multiple channels. To do this, use search to collect a list of videos that are type=='upcoming' from each channel and extract the timestamp from the collected video list. This process consumes quota of 100 (Search) + 1 (Video). I can do less than 100 searches, but is there any way I can do more searches?

I also tried to use "youtube-livestreaming-api", but I found that my API key was not valid. Can't I use this API because I am not YouTube Partner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interesting in using my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/commit/634acf3a7ea5cedabb8b7a74ad32f49f1b0b4cc2#diff-fe25e8545f067eb50fae0028b5dcdc76e168a985bd8806edcae066ae1f6a4f8bR104-R105) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com).

Indeed by requesting `https://yt.lemnoslife.com/search?part=id&channelId=CHANNEL_ID&eventType=upcoming` you will get for 0 quota the ids of upcoming streams of a given YouTube channel.

You can then use the returned video ids to pass them to the YouTube Data API v3 to get their timestamp of scheduled stream. In that way in the end for default 10,000 quota you don't make 99 searches but 500,000.

You can retrieve such a channel from [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLU12uITxBEPE5DRYdmNUdE2A6IdmjtyH2).

Comment: I tried with the playlistid you add in the [sample](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLU12uITxBEPE5DRYdmNUdE2A6IdmjtyH2), but, I don't get any data. URL: `https://yt.lemnoslife.com/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=PLU12uITxBEPE5DRYdmNUdE2A6IdmjtyH2`

Comment: It seems you don't understand my answer. Liu Ken is asking for a way to list upcoming livestreams of a given YouTube channel. Let's pick an upcoming video from the playlist I shared: 6COkjd-gbjk then let's get to the channel of this video: UCJ5v_MCY6GNUBTO8-D3XoAg then use my URL: https://yt.lemnoslife.com/search?part=id&channelId=UCJ5v_MCY6GNUBTO8-D3XoAg&eventType=upcoming and then we get in the response the original video so it's working properly. My tool and method is very precise, follow it and you'll get what the OP is looking for

Comment: Doesn't show from upcoming livestreams from YouTube live channel: channel_id `UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig` - link: https://yt.lemnoslife.com/search?part=id&channelId=UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig&eventType=upcoming - maybe I'm just confused.

Comment: The channelId you sent is a special YouTube channel managed by YouTube. This YouTube channel doesn't have any upcoming livestreams. The only thing this YouTube channel does is maintaining an up-to-date YouTube playlist of some upcoming videos of YouTube channels. Anyway don't lose time on the playlist example, just check this example https://www.youtube.com/c/WWE/videos?view=2&live_view=502 and my API https://yt.lemnoslife.com/search?part=id&channelId=UCJ5v_MCY6GNUBTO8-D3XoAg&eventType=upcoming and you will see that my API does what we expect it to do.

Comment: Sorry for the late confirmation. I checked your answer and everything works well. Thank you.